# rspec - why does a let variable need an @ instance symbol in the it but not in the expect?

Tags: rspec, instance-variables, memoization, let

For this test:

```
describe "can translate" do
  let(:from){592}
  it @from do
    expect(Translator.three_digits(from)).to eq 'five hundred ninety two'
  end
end
```

I need to refer to `from` as `@from` when using it in the `it` statement but as just `from` when using it in the `expect` test.  In each case trying to use the other format raises errors as unknown.  Why the difference?
Does it reflect something I'm not doing/understanding correctly?

After more digging I realized the @ instance variable isn't working correctly - it just isn't reporting an error because an @variable can be empty.  However if the tests fails and the test text descriptions is output the value for that variable is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try `expect{}` instead of `expect()`:

```
describe "can translate" do
  let(:from){592}
  it "some description here what I expect it to do" do
    expect{Translator.three_digits(from)}.to eq 'five hundred ninety two'
  end
end
```

or omit its description and do in one line:

```
it { expect{Translator.three_digits(from) }.to eq 'five hundred ninety two' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the `let(:from) { 592 }` declaration to also initialize a `@from` instance variable?  If so, I don't think it does.  If not, could you please expand upon why you need to refer to `from` as `@from` in your `it` block?  As far as I understand your question, the reason why your `@from` instance variable isn't working the way you expect it to is because it's `nil` because you haven't declared a `@from` anywhere in the spec.  Here's a small test:

```
describe 'foo' do
  let(:foo) { 1 }
  it "@foo's value is #{@foo.inspect}" do
    expect(foo).to eq(2) # deliberate fail
  end
end
```

The result:

```
1) foo @foo's value is nil # no @foo here
   Failure/Error: expect(foo).to eq(2)

     expected: 2
          got: 1

   (compared using ==)
```

As an aside, I think the potential for confusion when using instance variables in specs is exemplified in the following spec:

```
describe 'foo' do
  let(:foo) { 1 }
  before { @foo = 2 }
  @foo = 3
  it "@foo's value is #{@foo.inspect}" do
    expect(@foo).to eq(2) # this test passes cause it uses @foo in before block 
    expect(foo).to eq(2) # deliberate fail
  end
end
```

The result:

```
1) foo @foo's value is 3 # it block uses @foo in describe block 
   Failure/Error: expect(foo).to eq(2)

     expected: 2
          got: 1

   (compared using ==)
```